# How to mock a readonly property with mock?

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, pytest

How do you mock a readonly property with [mock](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/index.html)?

I tried:

```
setattr(obj.__class__, 'property_to_be_mocked', mock.Mock())
```

but the issue is that it then applies to all instances of the class... which breaks my tests.

Do you have any other idea? I don't want to mock the full object, only this specific property.

Answer (score 255, accepted):

I think the better way is to mock the property as `PropertyMock`, rather than to mock the `__get__` method directly.

It is stated in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.PropertyMock), search for `unittest.mock.PropertyMock`:
A mock intended to be used as a property, or other descriptor, on a class. `PropertyMock` provides `__get__` and `__set__` methods so you can specify a return value when it is fetched.

Here is how:

```
class MyClass:
    @property
    def last_transaction(self):
        # an expensive and complicated DB query here
        pass

def test(unittest.TestCase):
    with mock.patch('MyClass.last_transaction', new_callable=PropertyMock) as mock_last_transaction:
        mock_last_transaction.return_value = Transaction()
        myclass = MyClass()
        print myclass.last_transaction
        mock_last_transaction.assert_called_once_with()
```

Comment: I had to mock a class method decorated as `@property`. This answer worked for me when the other answer (and other answers on many other questions) did not.

Comment: this is the way it should be done. I wish there was a way to move the "accepted" answer

Comment: I find including the return value in the context manager call to be slightly cleaner:

```
with mock.patch('MyClass.last_transaction', new_callable=PropertyMock, return_value=Transaction()):
...
```

Comment: Indeed, I just moved the accepted answer to this one.

Comment: using mock.patch.object is also nice since you don't have to write the class name as a string (not really a problem in the example) and it's easier to detect/fix if you decide to rename a package and haven't updated a test

Comment: The thing is, what if I use `mock.patch` as a decorator and on the class? Is there a way?

Comment: This replaces the property with a static, non-callable, value. That's not an ideal type of mock. Ideally, it should be replaced by a callable.

Comment: Awesome. Stumbled upon this answer to mock a property. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 48):

Actually, the answer was (as usual) in the [documentation](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/examples.html#mocking-properties), it's just that I was applying the patch to the instance instead of the class when I followed their example.

Here is how to do it:

```
class MyClass:
    @property
    def last_transaction(self):
        # an expensive and complicated DB query here
        pass
```

In the test suite:

```
def test():
    # Make sure you patch on MyClass, not on a MyClass instance, otherwise
    # you'll get an AttributeError, because mock is using settattr and
    # last_transaction is a readonly property so there's no setter.
    with mock.patch(MyClass, 'last_transaction') as mock_last_transaction:
        mock_last_transaction.__get__ = mock.Mock(return_value=Transaction())
        myclass = MyClass()
        print myclass.last_transaction
```

Comment: people should use the other example. `mock.PropertyMock` is the way to do it!

Comment: That's correct, at time of writing `PropertyMock` did not exist.

Answer (score 20):

If the object whose property you want to override is a mock object, you don't have to use `patch`.

Instead, can create a [`PropertyMock`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.PropertyMock) and then override the property on the *type* of the mock. For example, to override `mock_rows.pages` property to return `(mock_page, mock_page,)`:

```
mock_page = mock.create_autospec(reader.ReadRowsPage)
# TODO: set up mock_page.
mock_pages = mock.PropertyMock(return_value=(mock_page, mock_page,))
type(mock_rows).pages = mock_pages
```

Comment: Bam, just what I wanted (autospec'd object with a property). And from a colleague no less ‍♂️

Comment: Also works well on several objects, because apparently, `Mock` constructor produces a new class everytime: `type(Mock()) == type(Mock())` is `False`.

Answer (score 15):

In case you are using [`pytest`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/) along with [`pytest-mock`](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-mock), you can simplify your code and also avoid using the context manger, i.e., the `with` statement as follows:

```py
def test_name(mocker): # mocker is a fixture included in pytest-mock
    mocked_property = mocker.patch(
        'MyClass.property_to_be_mocked',
        new_callable=mocker.PropertyMock,
        return_value='any desired value'
    )
    o = MyClass()

    print(o.property_to_be_mocked) # this will print: any desired value

    mocked_property.assert_called_once_with()
```

Comment: This also works well with `side_effect=['value1', 'value2', 'value3']` instead of using `return_value`, in case you need several return values consecutively.

Comment: that's alot cleaner and mocks in single statement.

Answer (score 13):

Probably a matter of style but in case you prefer decorators in tests, @jamescastlefield's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25424012/451710) could be changed to something like this:

```
class MyClass:
    @property
    def last_transaction(self):
        # an expensive and complicated DB query here
        pass

class Test(unittest.TestCase):
    @mock.patch('MyClass.last_transaction', new_callable=PropertyMock)
    def test(self, mock_last_transaction):
        mock_last_transaction.return_value = Transaction()
        myclass = MyClass()
        print myclass.last_transaction
        mock_last_transaction.assert_called_once_with()
```

Answer (score 3):

If you need your mocked `@property` to rely on the original `__get__`, you can create your custom `MockProperty`

```py
class PropertyMock(mock.Mock):

    def __get__(self, obj, obj_type=None):
        return self(obj, obj_type)
```

Usage:

```py
class A:

  @property
  def f(self):
    return 123


original_get = A.f.__get__

def new_get(self, obj_type=None):
  return f'mocked result: {original_get(self, obj_type)}'


with mock.patch('__main__.A.f', new_callable=PropertyMock) as mock_foo:
  mock_foo.side_effect = new_get
  print(A().f)  # mocked result: 123
  print(mock_foo.call_count)  # 1
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to test whether or not the mocked property was accessed you can simply patch it with the expected `return_value`.

```
with mock.patch(MyClass, 'last_transaction', Transaction()):
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I was directed to this question because I wanted to mock the Python version in a test. Not sure whether this is quite relevant to this question, but `sys.version` is obviously read-only (... though technically an "attribute" rather than a "property", I suppose).

So, after perusing this place and trying some stupidly complicated stuff I realised the answer was simplicity itself:

```
with mock.patch('sys.version', version_tried):
    if version_tried == '2.5.2':
        with pytest.raises(SystemExit):
            import core.__main__
        _, err = capsys.readouterr()
        assert 'FATAL' in err and 'too old' in err
```

... might help someone.