# How to programmatically replace a property accessor for a single instance?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a class that can be simplified to something like:

```
class Foo(object):
    @property
    def x(self):
        return 'Boo'

foo = Foo()
foo.x --> 'Boo'
```

I'm doing some testing/simulation where I want to change the `x` accessor property to return a different constant value, just for the `foo` instance. Obviously, I can't just use `foo.x = '13 Candles'` because it's a property! I tried:

```
foo.__dict__['x'] = '13 Candles'
```

But `foo.x` still returns `'Boo'` after that?!

I also tried

```
setattr(foo, 'x', '13 Candles')
```

Hoping that "bypassed" the accessor machinery. But no such luck. Just an error that it's a read only property.

Comment: If you've defined a property, you'll need to define a setter too.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Overriding properties in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7019643/overriding-properties-in-python)

Comment: Do you have control of this class?

Comment: @Loïc that's a pretty old question. The original question references keywords that predated Python2.3.

Comment: Or to put it another way, I checked it out fervently hoping it would be the answer I was looking for, and wasn't any closer to seeing the solution, other then thinking, this stuff (decorators) sure has evolved a bunch over the years.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga can you clarify? I wrote the Foo class, yes. I don't want to rewrite it to support this case necessarily, it's being used in production as is already.

Comment: It is not a duplicate question of the question above, because it is related to an instance, without changing the class. I would recommend the [unittest.mock](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html) standard library. If you google python+mock+property you will see that it is a duplicate of many questions and that the mock docs is a solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to mock a readonly property with mock?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11836436/how-to-mock-a-readonly-property-with-mock)