# What are the downsides to not using PropertyMock for stubbing a class instance?

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

If I am mocking a class instance object, setting one of its property attributes to a a pre-defined value (i.e., creating a stub), what are the downsides of implementing this without `PropertyMock`?

Example:

```
class MyQueue:
    @property
    def values(self):
        return self._values

    def pop(self):
        return self.values.pop(0)

def test_pops_first_item_in_queue():
    mock_queue = create_autospec(MyQueue,  instance=True)
    mock_queue.values = [1, 2, 3]

    popped_value = mock_counter.pop()
    
    assert popped_value == 1
    assert mock_counter.values == [2, 3]
    # This is false, but so is if we'd use PropertyMock(return_value=...) 
    assert mock_counter._values == [2, 3]
```

With this small example, I don't see any downsides here that could be resolved with `PropertyMock`

Related Questions:

- [How to mock a readonly property with mock?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11836436/how-to-mock-a-readonly-property-with-mock) answers here addresses those who want to mock the property for all instance created in the patched context or mocked class.